# Status Updates related to data entry

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, user, status

I am new to SharePoint and was tasked with a large project. Basically we are going to have a data entry point for information. Is there a way to track what the status of the data entry is if there were several steps in the review process. ie. budget submitted, budgeted being reviewed by manager, budget being reviewed by finance, budget approved.